# Meteor on Openshift gives errors for facebook and google+ login integrations

Tags: meteor, openshift, meteor-accounts

We have used DIY cartridge to install meteor on Openshift using http://www.tutas-labs.com/meteor-on-openshift/ and build an app, facebook and google+ login does not work and i get following errors during loading of app in firefox browser
1) Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss

On Facebook/Google+, xhr calls happens continuously but it will not log-in using facebook/google+

Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: Have you verified all your endpoints? We may need more information to assist you.

Comment: You may be using a 3G connection where your ISP has a proxy that doesn't support websockets. If you use SSL you can bypass this. The other option is to disable websockets: http://meteorpedia.com/read/Websockets

Comment: Started using node.js reverse proxy using 8443 port for https and here is xhr send results, Request URL:https://<mywebsite>.rhcloud.com:8443/sockjs/451/3fdfl586/xhr_send
Request Method:POST
Status Code:204 No Content